# How to use represent in field definition

Tags: rest, python-2.7, web2py

I am using web2py and am puzzled by how to use the represent attribute in my database field definition.

I have the following two table definitions:

```
my_info = db.define_table('my_info',
    Field('my_uuid', 'string', length=64, requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()], unique=True),
    Field('my_name', 'string', length=512, requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()]),
    Field('my_type', 'string', length=32, requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()]),
)

my_other_info = db.define_table('my_other_info',
    Field('my_other_uuid', 'string', length=64, requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()], unique=True),
    Field('my_info_id', 'reference my_info', requires=IS_IN_DB(db, db.my_info.my_uuid, '')),
    Field('my_other_name', 'string', length=512, requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()]),
    Field('my_other_type', 'string', length=32, requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()]),
)
```

It would help if I could get the value of `my_uuid` whenever I access the `my_info_id` field in the `my_other_info` table.

I tried something like:

```
represent=lambda id, row: db(db.my_info.id==row.my_info_id).select(db.my_info.my_uuid).first().as_dict()['my_uuid']
```

But this does not seem to be working for me and I think there is some major gap in my knowledge as to how I should go about this.

Please note that there is no form processing or any frontend processing involved in this application and I would like to use the represent attribute to cut down on DB queries in my REST API.

In addition the REST API is going to be accessed using a command line interface.

I hope someone can give me some pointers on getting represent to work.

Thanks,
nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "represent" function is correct, though the `.as_dict()` is unnecessary, and it can be further simplified as follows:

```
represent=lambda id, row: db.my_info(id).my_uuid
```

However, keep in mind that the "represent" attribute is only used when web2py displays data via `SQLTABLE`, `SQLFORM.grid`, and read-only `SQLFORM` edit forms. If you want to have the "represent" transformation applied in other contexts, you have to do so explicitly. One option is to use the `Rows.render()` method:

```
rows = db(db.my_other_info).select()
my_uuid = rows.render(0).my_info_id
```

The `.render()` method of a `Rows` object takes an index and returns that record with all of the "represent" attributes applied to its fields. If no index is supplied, it instead returns an iterator so you can loop over the records. If you don't want to convert all the fields, you can optionally supply a `fields` argument, which is a list of fields to convert.

Also, note that your `IS_IN_DB` validator is incorrect. Because the `my_info_id` field is storing record IDs of the `db.my_info` table, it should be `IS_IN_DB(db, db.my_info.id)`. Actually, to make things easier, you can just do:

```
my_info = db.define_table('my_info',
    Field('my_uuid', 'string', length=64, requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()], unique=True),
    ...,
    format='%(my_uuid)s')

my_other_info = db.define_table('my_other_info',
    Field('my_other_uuid', 'string', length=64, requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()], unique=True),
    Field('my_info_id', 'reference my_info'),
    ...)
```

When you define a reference field that references a table with a "format" attribute, the "format" attribute of the referenced table is used to generate a default `IS_IN_DB` validator and a default "represent" attribute for the reference field.

Comment: thanks for your great answer I think I have now got a much clearer picture of what I need to do. Cheers nav.

Comment: Note, you could also look into using a [virtual field](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Virtual-fields).